# Scrollbars in WPF Tab Item Issues

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, tabcontrol

I have a Tab Control that has a whole set of close able tab items, each tab item has View with a that has a scroll able section(each view is the same not same instance), the issue that I am having is that if you scroll on one tab its cascades to all the other tabs, I was wandering if someone can tell me how I can stop this from happening?
Thanks All :)

Comment: what's scrolling, a textbox?  What's the control in the tab pages that are scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior if your `TabControl` specifies a `ContentTemplate`.TabControls use virtualization, so they will re-use the template when you switch tabs instead of creating a new one each time.

This means the same `ScrollViewer` is being used regardless of which tab you are on. You can prove this by adding a `Loaded` event to your `ScrollViewer` and you'll see it only gets called once.

One way around this is to use a DataTemplate that has `x:Shared="False"`, so it won't share the template. I have not tested to see if there are any performance issues with this.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate" x:Shared="False">
    <local:UserControl1 />
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Test" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TestTemplate}" />
</Style>

...

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" />
```

Note that this seems to be very fussy... for example I need to put my `ScrollViewer` in a `UserControl` or it won't work. I also need to set `TabItem.ContentTemplate` instead of `TabControl.ContentTemplate`.